# Error while deploying Grails 2.5.1 application on Glassfish4

Tags: spring, grails, glassfish

Hi while i'm trying to deploy `grails 2.5.1` application on `glassfish 4` the below error occurs and while i can't this error while running the application

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationFailureListener': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginAttemptsService' while setting bean property 'loginAttemptsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginAttemptsService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
```

here what it's complain about :

```
class AuthenticationFailureListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent > {
def loginAttemptsService

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent e) {
    loginAttemptsService.failLogin(e.authentication.name)
}
```

}

if found that when i commented the below in the `resources.groovy` , i was able to deploy successfully.

```
beans = {

authenticationFailureListener(AuthenticationFailureListener) { loginAttemptsService = ref('loginAttemptsService') }
authenticationSuccessEventListener(AuthenticationSuccessEventListener) { loginAttemptsService = ref('loginAttemptsService') }
 }
```

i can't see anything wrong , any recommendations

Comment: Is the file groovy-all-x.x.x.jar present in the war under \WEB-INF\lib? Does it deploy with Tomcat?

Comment: @andi i updates the question

Comment: Sorry, I thought it could be that the groovy jar is missing at all. But if the app runs without the bean declaration, this should not be the case. I would search for the reason why there is a Classloader involved that does not have the groovy.jar in its classpath. Try tomcat to narrow down the root of the problem. Or try if it helps to copy the groovy-all.jar into the lib folder of the glassfish server. Perhaps there is a nested exception in the log that shows the root of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error disappeared when i added `groovy-all-xxx.jar` to `glassfish/domains/MYDOMAIN/lib/ext`